# href modification in <area> tag

Tags: jquery

if i want to change the href of an area tag depending on the random number that is assigned to a variable . how can i do that ?

i have tried using the formula `$('#id').attr('href', 'link');` but it didn't work out for me

here is my code:

```
<body>
<script>
var choose = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);


if (choose == 1){
$('#first').attr('href', 'true.html');
$('#second').attr('href', 'false.html');}

else{
$('#first').attr('href', 'false.html');
$('#second').attr('href', 'true.html');}

</script>

<map name="rockpos" id="rockys">
<area shape="rect" id="first" coords="1,1,137,270" href=""     />
<area shape="rect" id="second"coords="208,4,340,273" href=""     />
</map>

</body>
```

Comment: enclose your code in `$(function(){    -- your code  -- });`

Comment: What is not wrking out for you? I  tried in  a fiddle and it replaces the href.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
document.getElementById("#id").setAttribute("href","somelink");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your code inside `$(document).ready()`

try this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           var choose = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);


           if (choose == 1){
             $('#first').attr('href', 'true.html');
             $('#second').attr('href', 'false.html');}
           else{
             $('#first').attr('href', 'false.html');
             $('#second').attr('href', 'true.html');}
        });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, here is the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/9YJP7/)**

Hope you add the script to your head tag inorder to use jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Thank you